# Question about Python script compiled to .exe

Tags: python

I have a Question about compiling a python script to Executable. So If I compile a C/C++ static executable I know that it will work on other systems without the need of installing some frameworks or stuff. I am really not sure if Python scripts compiled to executable work on other systems without Python installed. So, Is it good and safe to compile python scripts to executable? If I convert a python script to executable and run it on systems without python installed an Error pops up saying `Failed to execute script emailmanager`

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you compile python using pyinstaller it creates a directory with the compiled executable and all the libraries it needs to run. Therefore you can distribute said directory and it should work on any system - even when python or used libraries are not installed